# Automatically find all methods that are used once

Tags: java, intellij-idea, static-code-analysis

For a large Java project I'd like get a list of all methods that are used (static analysis) exactly once within a certain scope, preferably within IntelliJ.

I can get a list of unused methods easily and I could manually go through each method and find the usages but that is too tedious. I searched within the available code inspections of IntelliJ 2017.3 but could not find a suitable inspection.

Context: I look for minimally dependent code, especially private functions which are used only once may get inlined, for example.

After the comment of [Andrey](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48811947/automatically-find-all-methods-that-are-used-once?noredirect=1#comment84642290_48811947) I tried using structural search.

- select menu `Edit/Find/Search Structurally`
- choose Existing Template `all methods of the class`
- select `Edit Variables`
- for variable `Method` uncheck the `Unlimited` option and set `Maximum Count` to 1

While this reduced the number of methods there are still some among them which are used (Alt+F7) more than once!

Comment: You can try using [Structural Search](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/structural-search-and-replace.html) for this. You can define the range number for occurrences for the target of the search.

Comment: @Andrey. Thanks. But unfortunately it doesn't seem to work. I still get results with more than one usages.

Comment: IntelliJ inspections are created to find things that are, or could be, problematic. There is nothing problematic, bad or wrong with a method that is used only once, and therefore there is no inspection to detect such methods. If you need, you can write a plugin to find such methods.

Comment: @yole That sounds a bit strange to me. Surely IntelliJ cannot be that omniscient to really be able to differentiate between things that could be problematic and things that categorically aren't. Besides, would it not be nice to use the tool sometimes also for things that might not directly be problematic? Anyway, if you are sure it's impossible, why not making an answer out of it?

Comment: IntelliJ is not omniscient, but it also doesn't have an infinite amount of resources, and those resources are spent on implementing inspections for things for which we understand how and why they are problematic.

Comment: @Yole I see and understand. For me not having this feature is problematic because I need to understand and modify a large yet not very known to me code base. I think the feature would help me writing better code, so not having it maybe could be seen as problematic at least for me. All I wanted to know was if IntelliJ contains the feature. With scripting and templates a lot is possible even with limited resources. I thought it was worth the try. It doesn't seem to be the case for understandable reasons. The question is basically answered.

Comment: I'm quite certain that inlining methods with a single usage will in most cases make a codebase worse, not better (and also harder to understand). When a piece of logic is extracted into a method, it has a name and a clear purpose. Inlining the method will remove the name and will make it harder to discern the purpose in a larger context.

Comment: @yole "Inlining the method will remove the name..." That's indeed what IntelliJ does when using the refactoring/inlining feature. Documentation in front of the method are deleted. That's why, when I used the feature, I first created a suitable comment on the first line of the method before inlining. I agree with the general statements about the usefulness of inlining methods. Still I think there are some useful cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such feature in IntelliJ IDEA out of the box, but it can be implemented as a third-party plugin.